# Functional way to get or update

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, function-composition

I have a cache and have two functions to get an item from the cache and put an item to the cache.

When getting item(from the cache), if key not exists I need to populate a value to it and return that value.

Following is a sample code

```
class CacheComp {
    cache = Map[String, Foo]

    get(id): Foo = {
        // case(id exists) => Return matching Foo

        // case(id not exists) => Create a Foo and update the cache with created Foo. Then return updated Foo
    } 

    put(id, Foo) = {
        // put element to the cache   
    }
}
```

In here I'm violating single responsibility principle(SRP) of `get(id)` function. How to do this without violating SRP? I can simply rename the function to `getOrUpdate(id)`. But are there any clean functional programming way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're aiming for a 'functional' solution, you want your cache `Map` to be immutable, because everything is immutable in the functional world. Note that `scala.collection.immutable.Map` has this method:

```
override def updated [B1 >: B](key: A, value: B1): Map[A, B1]
```

Now there is a small wrinkle -- once the map is updated, how do you use the cache with updated value? You need to change your interface for this.

```
type Cache = Map[String, Foo]

object Cache {
  def get(id: String, cache: Cache): (Foo, Cache) = cache.get(id) match {
    case Some(e) => (e,cache)
    case None => 
      val foo = makeFoo
      (foo, cache.updated(id, foo))
  }

  def put(id: String, foo: Foo, cache: Cache): Cache = cache.updated(id, foo)
}
```

That gives you a functional cache without side effects. I'd also further change `put` to `upsert` and check if a cache entry needs to be updated.

Answer (score 5):

There is already a `getOrElseUpdate` function defined on `mutable map`.

```
val cache = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
cache.getOrElseUpdate("lang", "scala")
```

Comment: I have never come across this :) nice one.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is similar to an *idempotent insert* that is *insert if the element does not exist, if it exists return the id of an existing object*. You have to keep in mind that no matter how you name the function it will still side-effect on the `cache`. Scala-wise you could go for things like `collectFirst`, `getOrElse` to make it nicer syntatically but the issue remains.
Code-wise:

```
val cache = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Foo]()
def get(id: String): Foo = cache.collectFirst { case(key, foo) if key == id => foo } match {
  case Some(foo) => foo
  case None => {
    val foo = new Foo //dunno what it would be
    cache += (id -> foo)
    foo
  }
}
```